# Why is this UDP client/server code not working?

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I'm experimenting with trying to send a single UDP message from one machine to another.  The client is an embedded Linux system that's connected to the internet via a modem.  No firewall is in place.  The server is a public VPS server I have.  Despite calling the client a number of times the server never receives anything.  Can anyone see what could be going wrong?

client:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   char sendline[1000];
   char recvline[1000];

   if (argc != 2)
   {
      printf("usage:  udpcli <IP address>\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

      sendto(sockfd,"abcd", 4,0,
             (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
}
```

Server:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t len;
   char mesg[1000];

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);
   bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

   for (;;)
   {
      len = sizeof(cliaddr);
      printf("calling recvfrom\n");
      n = recvfrom(sockfd,mesg,4,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
      printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
      mesg[n] = 0;
      printf("Received the following:\n");
      printf("%s",mesg);
      printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Try sending stuff from your pc using `nc -u`. Do you get anything on the server ?

Comment: No that didn't work either.

Comment: Okay, now shut down the server process and instead launch a `nc -u -l`. Back to your pc, try again the `nc -u`. If you don't see anything it's likely something on the way is blocking datagrams on that port. Experiment with a number of ports until you find one that gets through.

Comment: Tried a bunch of different ports and none of them seem to work.  Perhaps UDP is being blocked by the VPS provider?

Comment: Could be. Try port `53`, that usually goes through the internet. Also, are you sure you have the right args for `nc` ? Not to offend you, but maybe do a trial on localhost to make sure you are correctly using the flavour you have ?

Comment: Good suggestion on port 53.  I did get my C code to work if I ran the server on the embedded system and the client on my local PC, avoiding the VPS, so I can run my experiments now :)  Write up your port 53 suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it correct if you want.

Comment: I've enough rep. You should answer your own question, you have the most experience with it :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem looks like it was UDP traffic being blocked on my VPS server.  When I re-ran the server on the embedded system and the client on my Linux PC it worked fine.